# Lotusscript : Couldn't get RichText field when loading the document (before saving)

Tags: lotus-notes, attachment, lotusscript, richtext

I have an issue with lotusscript developement.
Well, this is my scenario :

1. I designed a form named "FORM"
2. Create a new Document using the form "FORM"
3. The form "FORM" contains a RichText Field named "ListPod"
4. When opening the document in EDIT mode, I want to attach automatically a file (C:\Files\file.pdf) directly in the field "ListProd"

I used the event "OnLoad" to access the RichText Field and do my work.

My problem is that the field "ListProd" doesn't exist yet. Any idea please?

Here is my source :

```
Sub Onload(Source As Notesuidocument)
    Dim fileName As String 
    fileName$ = Dir$( "c:\Files\*.pdf", 0 )
    Print fileName$
    If Not ( fileName$ = "" ) Then
        Dim object As NotesEmbeddedObject
        Dim rtItem As NotesRichTextItem
        Set rtItem = Source.Document.GetFirstItem("ListProd")
        If rtItem.Type = RICHTEXT Then
            Set object = rtitem.EmbedObject(EMBED_ATTACHMENT, "", "c:\Files\"+fileName$)            
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

"rtItem.Type" Throws an error because "rtItem" is NULL. What can I do to access this field please ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use `QueryOpen` event and try to recreate your item using `NotesRichTextItem` constructor:

```vb
Sub Queryopen(Source As Notesuidocument, Mode As Integer, Isnewdoc As Variant, Continue As Variant)

    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Dim rtitem As NotesRichTextItem
    Dim bIsNewDoc As Boolean

    Set doc = Source.Document

    bIsNewDoc = True

    If Not Isnewdoc And Not doc Is Nothing Then
        bIsNewDoc = doc.IsNewNote
    End If

    If Not bIsNewDoc And Mode% = 1 Then
        'Your code

        Call doc.RemoveItem("ListProd")
        Set rtitem = New NotesRichTextItem(doc, "ListProd")
        Call rtitem.EmbedObject(EMBED_ATTACHMENT, "", fileName$)

        'Your code
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tryed to do that but I found two fields "ListProd" after saving the document. In the other hand, the Pdf didn't appear in the place it should be !

Comment: @yeliliNatem Use `QueryOpen` event. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Good Idea Thank you! There is only one little problem : canno place the new ListProd in the same place on the form as the first one. I'll find a solution. thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

I found a soluion here

[Validate rich text fields for attachments without saving the UI document](http://searchdomino.techtarget.com/tip/Validate-rich-text-fields-for-attachments-without-saving-the-UI-document)

Using : uidoc.refresh True, I could transfer All front-end modified information to back-end. And so, i've got access to my 'ListProd' field without saving :)

Hopr it helps you :)